# No voice after running?

Tags: python, gtts

The output of the code below should be a voice saying, 'Welcome to geeks for geeks!', but I'm getting 1, why?

```
from gtts import gTTS 
import os  
mytext = 'Welcome to geeksforgeeks!'
language = 'en'
myobj = gTTS(text=mytext, lang=language, slow=False) 
myobj.save("welcome.mp3")  
os.system("mpg321 welcome.mp3")
```

Comment: add the code here

Comment: Welcome to SO.Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and take the time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the other links found on that page.

Answer (score 0):

This code is perfect and should work provided you have installed `gtts` into your pip environment and `mpg321` is on your path. I tested this code on Mac OS (where I did `brew install mpg321` and on Ubuntu 18.04 (`sudo apt install mpg321`). In both cases, I heard a voice saying "welcome to geeks for geeks".

If you want more help with this, you will have to provide more details about the context in which this code is being run. Here are some commands you should post the output of, to give more info people like me who want to help you. :)

```
python --version

pip freeze

uname -a
```

Also, have you tried playing a different mp3 file with mpg321? It might be that mpg321 is not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create the audio file and play it with your code. I first had to `sudo apt install mpg321` and `pip install gTTS` .

I have published a Repl.it with the code working at:   https://replit.com/@redten/StackOverflow-Q-62257928?v=1

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.